# Wait for AdMob free reward video event inside a function (Ionic/Typescript)

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I have a function that checks if the user saw or need to see a reward video to be able to use a function in my ionic app:

```
let canUseThisFunction = await this.someService.canUseFunction();

if(canUseThisFunction){
     console.log("can use");
} else {
    console.log("can NOT use");
}
```

and the check function is something like:

```
canUseFunction(){
    let canUse = await this.checkInBackend.checkIfUserHasReward();

    if(!canUse){
        await this.adService.showRewardVideo();   
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

The problem I had is that after `checkIfUserHasReward()` calls `admob.rewardVideo.show()` it resolves just "OK" while the reward video is running.

```
..
this.admob.rewardVideo.config(rewardVideoConfig);

        return this.admob.rewardVideo.prepare().then((prepareReward) => {
            console.log("prepareReward", prepareReward);
            return this.admob.rewardVideo.show();
        }).then(rewardShowed => {
            console.log("rewardShowed", rewardShowed);
            return rewardShowed;
        }).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

I can get the reward event using

```
(document as any).addEventListener("admob.rewardvideo.events.REWARD")
```

but it resolves outside my `canUseFunction()`. Is there a way to catch this `eventListener` inside another function?

Comment: You should not cast to `any`.

Comment: I was not sure how to get the "oficial" document reference and without `any` typescript said it was an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `new Promise` constructor to create a promise that you can resolve at will:

```
return new Promise(resolve => document.addEventListener("...", resolve);
```

Comment: Doesn't that create an event listener every time I return the promise? (that is every time the user sees the video)

Comment: Yes, it does.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: The thing is the user can (eventually) see more than one video. Then there will be to many event listeners (each one created after a video was played). Would not that create a memory leak? or I am understanding something wrong?

Comment: @distante: You're right; you can remove the event handler when the promise resolves.